# Manual keypads shown to user when an editText is highlighted

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, keypad

I have a number of editText's in my view and I want to be able to make some adjustments to the keypad that points up for the user when they highlight the EditText.

In particular
- Making a capitals only keypad?
- Removing the auto-correct feature?
- Adding non-english characters to the first screen of the keypad e.g. "ñ"

Is there a simple approach for changing this keypad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you don't have that much control of the on-screen keyboard that is displayed to the users. However, turning off autocorrect and making all characters capitals is a possibility, you simply need to set the `android:inputType` attribute in your XML. Here are [the values that you can use](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) (you can also OR `|` them). It would look like `android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textNoSuggestions"`.

I wouldn't worry about the Ñ or other weird characters. Most of those are easy to get by just long pressing on a key (in this case, the N).